# what went wrong with my sharepoint server deployment?

Tags: sharepoint-server, azure, sql

i have an azure subscription and i am trying to create a sharepoint server 2016 with an azure sql managed instance. i followed the steps from this article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/deploy-azure-sql-managed-instance-with-sharepoint-servers-2016-2019#environment) and here's what i did:

1. create resource group `sharepoint-server-deployment`
2. add vnet `sharepoint-server-deployment-vnet` to `sharepoint-server-deployment`
3. add a second subnet `subnet2` in addition to the `default` subnet on `sharepoint-server-deployment-vnet`
4. create a windows datacenter 2019 virtual machine `vm1` within  the `default` subnet
5. connect to `vm1` through rdp and add the `active directory` feature in the add features wizard
6. promote `vm1` to a domain controller and set up an ad forest
7. create windows datacenter 2019 vm `vm2` in the `default subnet`
8. connect to `vm2` through rdp and download sharepoint server 2016 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57462
9. install prerequisites and install sharepoint server 2016
10. create an azure sql managed instance `managedinstance` in `subnet2`
11. run the following from the sharepoint management shell on `vm2`:

```
$farmcred = get-credential # i used my credentials for signing in to vm2
$dbcred = get-credential # i used the admin credentials for managedinstance
$farmpwd = read-host -prompt "enter farm password" -assecurestring # i used the password i would like for the farm to have
new-spconfigurationdatabase -databaseserver managedinstance -databasename sharepoint_config -farmcredentials $farmcred -databasecredentials $dbcred -passphrase $farmpwd -localserverrole SingleServerFarm
```

i am getting that the server does not exist or current user does not have access to connect to it, pls help!